# EditText doesn't show up

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have layout for my activity and it shows up everything besides two edittexts, here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hrle.androidapp.activity.ReadPostActivity"
android:id="@+id/arp">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_rp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slika"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="141dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/autor"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/naslov"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/autor"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
    android:text="Autor: "
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datum"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autor"
    android:text="Datum: "
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lokacija"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datum"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Lokacija: "
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/likes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/opis"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_like"

     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dislikes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/likes"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/opis"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dislike" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/opis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/slika"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/naslov_za_unos"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/lv_comments"
    android:layout_below="@id/likes"
    android:hint="Unesite naslov"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/opis_za_unos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/lv_comments"
    android:layout_below="@id/naslov_za_unos"
    android:hint="Unesite opis"
    android:inputType="text"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dugme_potvrde_kom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dislikes"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:text="Objavi"

    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lv_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/likes"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
     />


    </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Here is the picture of design, edittexts should show up on position which I marked on picture. Can anyone figure out what makes it not show? And yes, I did everything in activity(findViewById etc.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcbz2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with these lines of code, I have used the `LinearLayout` for your view alignment, have a look in below solution

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/arp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hrle.androidapp.activity.ReadPostActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_rp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slika"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/autor"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naslov"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autor"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
        android:text="Autor: "
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datum"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autor"
        android:text="Datum: "
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lokacija"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datum"
        android:text="Lokacija: "
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/likes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/opis"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_like"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dislikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/opis"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/likes"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dislike"


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slika"

        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dislikes"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/naslov_za_unos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/lv_comments"
                android:layout_below="@id/likes"
                android:hint="Unesite naslov"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/opis_za_unos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/lv_comments"
                android:layout_below="@id/naslov_za_unos"
                android:hint="Unesite opis"

                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dugme_potvrde_kom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dislikes"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Objavi"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lv_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_input"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @MarkoLazarevic Welcome dost...Happy to help..Keep happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/naslov_za_unos"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_above="@id/opis_za_unos"
android:layout_below="@id/likes"
android:layout_alignParentStart = true
android:hint="Unesite naslov"
android:inputType="text"
/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/opis_za_unos"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@id/lv_comments"
android:layout_below="@id/naslov_za_unos"
android:layout_alignParentStart = true
android:hint="Unesite opis"
android:inputType="text"
/>
```

Comment: doesn't work, I added linear layout and it works now